# JavaScript code not working within a callback

Tags: javascript

In the following JavaScript code, if warnBeforeNew is false, the file open code works. However, it doesn't if warnBeforeNew is true, instead giving an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined".

I don't know if this is to do with scoping, but how do I get the file loading code to work within the callback? Thanks.

```
Editor.prototype.open = function(path) {
  if (Editor.warnBeforeNew==true){
    this.showDialog({
        dialogLabel: 'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to discard them and open a different file?',
        submitLabel: 'Discard',
        cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
        submitCallback: function() {
          Editor.warnBeforeNew=false;
          this.filesystem.root.getFile(path, {}, this.load.bind(this), error.bind(null, "getFile " + path));
        }
    });
  } else {
    this.filesystem.root.getFile(path, {}, this.load.bind(this), error.bind(null, "getFile " + path));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save the value of `this` because when the callback is called, it's with a different receiver than the external function :

```
if (Editor.warnBeforeNew==true){
    var thing = this; // choose a more meaningful name if possible...
    this.showDialog({
        dialogLabel: 'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to discard them and open a different file?',
        submitLabel: 'Discard',
        cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
        submitCallback: function() {
          Editor.warnBeforeNew=false;
          thing.filesystem.root.getFile(path, {}, thing.load.bind(thing), error.bind(null, "getFile " + path));
        }
    });
  } else {
    this.filesystem.root.getFile(path, {}, this.load.bind(this), error.bind(null, "getFile " + path));
  }
```

Comment: You forgot to replace `this` with `thing` in the bind

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch the scope out side the callback and use it.

```
Editor.prototype.open = function(path) {
var that=this;
  if (Editor.warnBeforeNew==true){
    this.showDialog({
        dialogLabel: 'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to discard them and open a different file?',
        submitLabel: 'Discard',
        cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
        submitCallback: function() {
          Editor.warnBeforeNew=false;
          that.filesystem.root.getFile(path, {}, that.load.bind(that), error.bind(null, "getFile " + path));
        }
    });
  } else {
    this.filesystem.root.getFile(path, {}, this.load.bind(this), error.bind(null, "getFile " + path));
  }
};
```

Comment: You forgot to replace `this` with `that` where the `load` method is bound

Comment: ya you are right `that.filesystem.root.getFile(path, {}, that.load.bind(that), error.bind(null, "getFile " + path));`

Answer (score 0):

The `submitCallback` to your `showDialog` method needs to be bound, too - it accesses `this.filesystem.root.…` which fails.

```
this.showDialog({
    …,
    submitCallback: function() {
      Editor.warnBeforeNew=false;
      this.filesystem.root.getFile(path, {}, this.load.bind(this), error.bind(null, "getFile " + path));
    }.bind(this)
//    ^^^^^^^^^^
});
```